# Get the rest of the results with a single query

Tags: php, mysql

Previously: Select2 issues

Changed to: A strongly related SQL question. (Don't want to waste the bounty as I did not get an answer and my bounty is still open!)

Basically, I have 2 queries. One is general, and one is based on a search.

one: get everything (no issues here)

```
SELECT store_info.storeID, store_info.name, store_info.address, store_info.phone, GROUP_CONCAT(brands.name) AS brands
FROM store_info, brands, stores, store_brands
WHERE stores.city = $cityID
AND store_brands.store =  stores.ID
AND brands.id = store_brands.brand
AND stores.ID = store_info.storeID
GROUP BY store_info.storeID
ORDER BY store_info.name
```

This query does exactly what I want it to do. It gives me stores with the brands formatted as `brand1,brand2,brand3,brand4,brand5` etc.

Now, I also have a search function, where you can search for a store based on the brands. It's basically the same query with a small tweak **(issues here)**:

```
SELECT store_info.storeID, store_info.name, store_info.address, store_info.phone, GROUP_CONCAT(brands.name) AS brands
FROM store_info, brands, stores, store_brands
WHERE stores.city = $cityID 
AND store_brands.store =  stores.ID
AND brands.ID = store_brands.brand
AND stores.ID = store_info.storeID
AND brands.ID IN (" . implode(",", $brandIDs) . ")
GROUP BY store_info.storeID
ORDER BY store_info.name
```

The issue with this last query is that I still want it to return all the brands. I simply want to manipulate the brands that were searched for later on. The way I see it, I *should* be able to do it in multiple ways:

1 ) Return all the brands in the query and manipulate the brands when going through them in php (I have the search terms stored, but I don't know how to do this without getting all the stores, which is not something I want to do)

2 ) Return 1 field with the matching brands that were searched for, and another field with  the remaining brands. (Ideal option, but I don't know how. Placing the entire query into a join with a tweak seems inefficient)

3 ) (Seems inefficient and I don't like it) get the found stores from the query, to run a new query looking for the brands related to the found stores, then combine the results with php. However, this would add an extra query and efficiency is priority.

I run into the issue that if someone searches for say, 2 brands, and there's stores that match with both, it will only show 1 of the 2 brands. (The first hit, I'm guessing).

Any help with this last query would very much be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**Edit: a bit more insight into the search function**
The search function searches for stores that are related to the brands searched for. It should show the stores that are connected to said brands, but not limit itself to returning only the brands that were searched for.

Comment: What is the search bar? I don't see it in your example. What do you mean "taps"?

Comment: mobile taps. Same as a desktop click.
The search bar is... well... the bar in which you type your search terms. It's a text-input that select2 creates. Once you type in it, it will give you a dropdown with results. You can then select (multiple) results as "tags" (very much like tags work on here, only you can leave it open)
However, when you reselect the search bar after having selected your options, select2 will reïnitiate and empty the search bar.

Comment: whats the aim to make tags property display:none ??

Comment: It will help if you can narrow down the problem statement without the extra code (ajax call, e.t.c).

Comment: Mohammed, That because the tags will push out the search bar, otherwise. The dropdown already shows what's selected. Tags are redundant. -@SelvakumarArumugam done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` ignores `NULL`, so you can just create a `GROUP_CONCAT` of your matches like so :

```
SELECT
store_info.storeID,
store_info.name,
store_info.address,
store_info.phone,
GROUP_CONCAT(brands.name) AS brands,
GROUP_CONCAT(
  CASE WHEN brands.ID IN (" . implode(",", $brandIDs) . ")
    THEN brands.name
    ELSE NULL
  END
) AS available_brands
FROM
stores
INNER JOIN store_info ON (stores.ID = store_info.storeID)
INNER JOIN store_brands ON (stores.ID = store_brands.store)
INNER JOIN brands ON (store_brands.brand = brands.id)
WHERE stores.city = $cityID
GROUP BY store_info.storeID
ORDER BY store_info.name
```

**Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83e576/1

Comment: I took the liberty to convert your comma separated joins into explicitly joined tables.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what that means, but thank you =)
Anyway, this query actually works! It's showing me both the matches and the list of brands. Perfect! - however, it shows all non-matches with a `NULL`. Is there any way to not retrieve these non-matched stores in the first place?

Comment: You might need some clause to not return the stores that have neither of the search brands. When removing the `stores.city` clause in your fiddle, it will return two stores that do not have Nike nor Adidas.

Comment: if I add `AND store_brands.brand IN(18)`, it will once more only return 1 brand in the total brands list. My SQL knowledge really isn't my proudest area... I have no experience with inner joins at all. (I used to work with umbraco so I never got into the databases)

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean when you say a non matched store?

Comment: Someone just made a comment about using `HAVING LENGTH(brands) > 0`... I simply changed it to `HAVING LENGTH(available_brands) > 0` and it worked. I am now getting results of only matched stores and brands, with a grouped result of the actual matches. Thank you very much! 
I do not know why this comment was removed, though. If it was removed for a specific reason, I'd like to know. Otherwise, I'll mark the answer as accepted as soon as the "HAVING LENGTH(available_brands) > 0" has been added :)

Comment: a non-matched store, meaning "available_brands" is "null". But that issue has been solved with `HAVING LENGTH(available_brands) > 0`. I just hope it won't ruin the efficiency ;)

Comment: Oh, one last thing.
How would I go about it now, to add another column with a count of how many brands were matched? (basically the same as available_matches, only with just a count)? That would really wrap this up neatly!

Comment: I was the one who put the `HAVING` comment there, but was not sure it resolved your issue, so I decided instead to ask for clarification.

Comment: `SUM(
  CASE WHEN brands.ID IN (" . implode(",", $brandIDs) . ")
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
) AS available_brands_count`

Comment: If we ever cross paths, I will definitely give you a beer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could just join the `store_brands` table a second time (`AS restraint` in the code below) and put the restriction on that one:

```
SELECT store_info.storeID, store_info.name, store_info.address, store_info.phone, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(brands.name)) AS brands
FROM store_info, brands, stores, store_brands, store_brands AS restraint
WHERE stores.city = $cityID 
AND store_brands.store =  stores.ID
AND brands.ID = store_brands.brand
AND stores.ID = store_info.storeID
AND restraint.ID IN (" . implode(",", $brandIDs) . ")
GROUP BY store_info.storeID
ORDER BY store_info.name
```

By joining the table twice, it will be used (1) for all the brands available in that store and (2) to limit the selected stores to the ones, that have one or more specified brands.

Comment: Did you add `store_brands AS restraint` to your list of `FROM` tables? It works well for me.

Comment: Yes, it was because it was supposed to be .brand instead of .ID, my bad. Anyway, it's not working. It's returning all stores, and therefore it is no different from a query simply getting everything. I'm getting 81 results -- I should be getting 4

Comment: Could you create an SQLFiddle? I recreated a simpler problem (just having stores and brands) and it works. Depending on your database schema, it may not be wise to just `JOIN` but `INNER JOIN` the tables.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I've completely rebuilt all my queries like this (with a now much, MUCH better understanding thanks to you guys!) and I do indeed work with multiple joins of the same table to get specific data with different relationships from the same table. -- Just wanted to give you props for opening my eyes to it and will leave an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

What about a [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) statement in the `SELECT` clause that returns true or false based on the matching criteria, that is, if the `brands.ID` is in the list of `$brandIDs`.

```sql
SELECT
  store_info.storeID,
  store_info.name,
  store_info.address,
  store_info.phone,
  GROUP_CONCAT(brands.name) AS brands,
  (
    CASE 
    WHEN brands.ID IN (" . implode(",", $brandIDs) . ") THEN 1
    ELSE 0 --no match
    END 
  ) AS matches
FROM store_info, brands, stores, store_brands
WHERE stores.city = $cityID 
AND store_brands.store =  stores.ID
AND brands.ID = store_brands.brand
AND stores.ID = store_info.storeID
GROUP BY store_info.storeID
ORDER BY store_info.name
```

The idea is that if the `brands.ID` is one of the ids in `$brandIDs` then a `1` will be returned in the `matches` column.  For anything else, a `0` will be returned.

Comment: By matching criteria you mean the ID's of the brands? It's just simple ID's like 25, 36, etc. 
I'm going to try this right now.

Comment: It's not matching with anything, so this isn't working. I do not fully understand this query, so I wouldn't know why. (I'm not getting any errors, and I know the IDs I'm working with are supposed to match up)

Comment: It should return all the results like the first query, but with an additional column where if the `brands.ID` is in `$brandIDs` then a `1` will be returned.

Comment: It's grouped by store, there will be multiple brands.  This query will not work.